# Colouring a tree with two colour

Tags: algorithm, tree

I am having a tree and i want to color each node `black or white`. A tree is said to be valid colored if 
`For every node N there exist at least One neighbor with the same color as of N`

**My Approach:**
let construct a dp[2][N] where 0,1 represent Black and white

```
ways = (dp[0][i1]+dp[1][i1])*(dp[0][i2]+dp[1][i2)*.....i upto All Children of N

   dp[0][N] = (ways-Number of ways when all the children are 1)
   dp[1][N] = (ways-Number of ways when all the children are 0)
```

But my approach is not giving me correct answer ? Please help me what i am missing ?

Comment: For the statement you described it's enough to color all the nodes in the same color.

Comment: Which programming contest is this from, Modiji?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each node `u`, let `C(u)` be the number of valid colorings of the subtree rooted at `u`, and let `A(u)` be the number of colorings in which all proper descendants of `u` have an identically colored neighbor ("almost valid"). The recurrence is

```
C(u) = A(u) - 2 product_{v is a child of u} (C(v)/2)
A(u) = 2 product_{v is a child of u} (C(v)/2 + A(v)/2)
```

The logic for `A(u)` is that (1) there are two colors for the root (2) each child `v` colored differently from `u` must be valid (3) each child `v` colored the same as `u` must be almost valid. The logic for `C(u)` is that the possible colorings where all children are different from their parent are only almost valid.